# Regex in Android JAVA - How to specify more than 9 backreferences?

Tags: java, android, regex, reference, backreference

I use multiple groups in a Regex search and replace many parts of a string. I use $1 $2 etc in Android JAVA when using String.replaceFirst.

If I use more than nine groups in my Regex search when trying to reference them in replaceFirst for example $10 , it will replace the first back reference and then prints a literal 0.

Is there anyway I can use a tenth reference? Is there a different way of referencing it?

Example, but I'm trying to use more than nine back references. $10 sees only $1.

```
String.replaceFirst("(hello)(.*)(this)","$1middle$2");
```

Comment: Try `${10}`. Although in *Java*, [`$10` works as expected](https://ideone.com/y44LKM).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** *If you experience that `$10` is treated as `$1` and a `0`, then your regex doesn't have 10 capture groups.*

The `$` back-references in the replacement value is documented in the javadoc for the [`appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) method:

> The replacement string may contain references to subsequences captured during the previous match: Each occurrence of `${name}` or `$g` will be replaced by the result of evaluating the corresponding `group(name)` or `group(g)` respectively. For `$g`, the first number after the `$` is always treated as part of the group reference. **Subsequent numbers are incorporated into `g` if they would form a legal group reference.** Only the numerals `'0'` through `'9'` are considered as potential components of the group reference. If the second group matched the string `"foo"`, for example, then passing the replacement string `"$2bar"` would cause `"foobar"` to be appended to the string buffer. A dollar sign (`$`) may be included as a literal in the replacement string by preceding it with a backslash (`\$`).

So, let's say we have 11 groups:

```
System.out.println("ABCDEFGHIJKLMN".replaceFirst("(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)",
                                                 "$11$10$9$3$2$1"));
```

Here we capture the first 11 characters as individual groups, so e.g. `group(1)` returns `"A"` and `group(11)` returns `"K"`. The input string has 14 characters, so the last 3 (`LMN`) are not replaced. The result is:

`KJICBALMN`

If we remove capture group 11 from the regex, then `$11` is not a legal group reference, and will be interpreted as `$1` and the literal `1`:

```
System.out.println("ABCDEFGHIJKLMN".replaceFirst("(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)",
                                                 "$11$10$9$3$2$1"));
```

Prints:

`A1JICBAKLMN`

So, if you experience that `$10` is treated as a `$1` back-reference and a literal `0`, then **your regex doesn't have 10 groups**.

Comment: Hi,I tried your example. I'm using Android Studio.
The Android JAVA version it uses must not support this. I get this output - A1A0ICBALMN

Answer (score 0):

You can also [name them](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname) with `(?<name>...)` and then reference them with `${name}`.

```
String.replaceFirst("(?<g1>hello)(?<g2>.*)(?<g3>this)","${g1}middle${g2}");
```